# Rules about Prop and Set in UTT

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, dependent-type

In Luo's UTT (type theory which is used in Agda, Idris, and other dependently typed programming languages), there're are two rules for $\Pi$ types. One for $\mathsf{Prop}$ and one for $\mathsf{Set}$. In the one for $\mathsf{Prop}$ we have no constraints on the universe of a parameter. In the one for $\mathsf{Set}(i)$, we have.

Why it was done in this way? Will anything bad happen in such a case?

P.S. Basically I want to understand why $\mathsf{Prop}$ has special treatment in the theory. I.e. why we can't choose $\mathsf{Type}(0)$ for propositions, then removed the $\mathsf{Type}(i)$ condition in the $\Pi$ types' argument, and as a consequence have more uniform set of axioms.

P.P.S. In Luo's thesis I read that Calculus of inductive constructions (CIC) where this universe was introduce was created as a mix between Martin-Löf type theory (MLTT) and System F. Does $\mathsf{Prop}$ correspond to the union of all the existing universes?

P.P.P.S. UTT is described in Luo's PhD thesis and book here: http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/zhaohui/books.html

Comment: Question would be more readable if you expanded some of the acronyms. Also, a well-formulated question should not require several PSs.

Comment: I'll let Konstantin expand "UTT".

Comment: @DaveClarke What is PS?

Comment: PS is P.S. without the does.

Comment: @DaveClarke Ok. I will try to formulate question better the next time.

Comment: FWIW, I doubt that Agda and Idris use UTT, as they are completely predicative, and based on MLTT with countably many universes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say that a universe $U$ is *impredicative* if the product $\prod_{x : A} B(x)$ is in $U$ whenever $B(x)$ is in $U$ for all $x$, and $A$ is arbitrary, i.e., not necessarily in $U$.

Are there any impredicative universes? Let us think about what an impredicative universe would be for sets: a set $U$ such that for every family of sets $B : A \to U$, no matter how large $A$ is, $\prod_{x : A} B(x)$ is in $U$. That's only possible in two cases: when $U$ contains the singleton (or many copies of it) and when it contains the empty set and the singleton (or many copies of it). This is so because a product of sets which are all singletons or empty is again such a set. If $U$ contains a set $S$ with at least two elements then $S^U$ (which is a special case of a product) will fail to be contained in $U$ for cardinality reasons.

Of course, we recognize that the case $U = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ is just the case when $U$ is the set of *truth values*, i.e., $\mathsf{Prop}$. This is one reason why $\mathsf{Prop}$ is treated differently: it is impredicative – not only in classical set theory but also more generally, because truth values are closed under $\forall$. Note that $\forall$ and $\prod$ coincide on families of sets that all contain at most one element.

In system $F$ we have impredicativity because types there are closed under $\forall$ ranging over the whole universe of types, and $\forall$ behaves like $\prod$.

One could hope that there are other models, where for instance $\mathsf{Type}_i$ is impredicative. Indeed, there are realizability models of (extensional) type theory that contain an impredicative universe of sets (as opposed to truth values). However, one cannot have *two* impredicative universes such that one is a member of the other, because one can then cook up a Burali-Forti paradox.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't imagine how I would find this out without your answer (and learn dep types without your other answers here).

Comment: May I ask why you're learning this stuff?

Comment: Basically, I want to understand tradeoffs which we have when we design dependently typed language, to implement one myself (I already implemented a language which is similar to what you implemented in your blog but with inductive types). I am doing this, since I want to apply projectional editors, the thing which I am working at JetBrains, to dependent types and I feel that it's the area where they are currently most useful. Since the length of the comment is limited I will write you email, where I explain this in more detail.